# Android smack stops working

Tags: android, smack

I am playing around Smack for android - writing a chat client using xmpp protocol. I used patched Smack from here http://people.apache.org/~dims/android/XMPPClient-2.zip
Yesterday, I could chat from my phone (with an jabber.org account) to an gmail account, and it worked well for several times connect/disconnect in about 30 minutes. But today I came into office, tried to chat again - and it just doesn't work. It's weird. Have anyone ever met that problem ?

Best,
Son

Comment: try to write log. and see what happened to it. you even can write a file to log anything what happened. and see the weird things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, that was the problem from Gmail account. I still don't know why, but when I use 2 Jabber accounts then there's on problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Hungson.

Google has introduced one more security layer. Its been there for quite some time.

For any third party apps that access gmail or any google service needs to be enabled from

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Thereafter you shouldn't see this issue.
Please try once.